# invite friends via web portal in V2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a question regarding invite friends via web portal in V2.0

I have designed a website, where I have given a functionality to login through facebook.
If the user's logs into the website we get his friend-list for user's those are not using our application on facebook.
We have given the invite friends functionality to invite his(user's) friend to join our site using send dialog box.

I have implemented it in V1.0 but as I move to V2.0 I am facing problem in invite friend as follows. I am using Taggable friend's API.

1. I am not able to get the user's friend's USER-ID so that it can appear in TO field of send dailog box
2. In v1 I am able to get USER-ID but In case of V2.0 I'm getting some alph-numeric value
3. So in that case I'm getting Invalid parameter error for USER-ID

So My question is whether I'm doing some thing wrong or You havn't given the support for this yet.
If not, then I want to know till when you will give support for this.

Hope you will reply soon.

Thank you

Comment: First of all, `taggable_friends` is the wrong endpoint for this – `invitable_friends` would be correct. But you are only allowed to use that when your app is a Game with a Canvas implementation. Alternatives are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: My Quesiton is following .
Is facebook support invite friend functionality for non canvas non game app using website?.

Comment: Read the FAQ section that I linked to please.

Comment: According to link you shared, facebook is not supporting invite friend functionality for non games app. But Is facebook planing to support such feature in future ?

Comment: If I could predict the future, I would not be commenting on SO … What alternatives you have _now_, is listed in that document.